# Riverpod attempt after reading Andrea's tutorial. UI not updating

Tags: flutter, riverpod

I read one of Andrea's tutorials and tried to write a sample app.

Issue: The build doesn't appear to re-run when the value changes.

The intention is to tap the button and see the Text widget update.  The button tap does appear to write shared preferences based on console print.  I don't see the equivelent of a 'notifyListeners' in this Riverpod Provider - that's what I think I am missing.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_riverpod/flutter_riverpod.dart';
import 'package:shared_preferences/shared_preferences.dart';

class SettingsRepository {
  const SettingsRepository(this.sharedPreferences);

  final SharedPreferences sharedPreferences;

  bool onboardingComplete() {
    return sharedPreferences.getBool('onboardingComplete') ?? false;
  }

  Future<void> setOnboardingComplete(bool complete) {
    return sharedPreferences.setBool('onboardingComplete', complete);
  }
}

final sharedPreferencesProvider = Provider<SharedPreferences>((ref) {
  throw UnimplementedError();
});

final settingsRepositoryProvider = Provider<SettingsRepository>((ref) {
  // watch another provider to obtain a dependency
  final sharedPreferences = ref.watch(sharedPreferencesProvider);
  // pass it as an argument to the object we need to return
  return SettingsRepository(sharedPreferences);
});

/// asynchronous initialization can be performed in the main method
Future<void> main() async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  final sharedPreferences = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
  runApp(ProviderScope(
    overrides: [
      // override the previous value with the new object
      sharedPreferencesProvider.overrideWithValue(sharedPreferences),
    ],
    child: const MyApp(),
  ));
}

class MyApp extends ConsumerStatefulWidget {
  const MyApp({super.key});

  @override
  ConsumerState<MyApp> createState() => _MyAppState();
}

class _MyAppState extends ConsumerState<MyApp> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return const MaterialApp(
      home: MyHomePage(),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends ConsumerStatefulWidget {
  const MyHomePage({super.key});

  @override
  ConsumerState<MyHomePage> createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends ConsumerState<MyHomePage> {

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {

    print('build');
    return Scaffold(
      body: SafeArea(
        child: Column(
          children: [
            //The objective is to get this Text to reflect the current value
            Text(
                'Value: ${ref.watch(settingsRepositoryProvider).onboardingComplete()}'),
            ElevatedButton(
              onPressed: () {
                var v =
                    ref.read(settingsRepositoryProvider).onboardingComplete();

                // the console shows this changing on each button press
                print('Setting ${!v}');

                ref.read(settingsRepositoryProvider).setOnboardingComplete(!v);
              },
              child: const Text('Toggle'),
            )
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: I just skimmed this but I didn't see any anything that would trigger a notification on updating the SharedPreferences instance.  Missing that leg.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like the issue might be due to the missing update notification to the UI after the value is changed in the SettingsRepository. In Riverpod, to update the UI when a value changes, you can use StateNotifier or StateNotifierProvider.
This  introduces a SettingsNotifier that extends StateNotifier. It manages the state of whether onboarding is complete or not. The settingsProvider uses this notifier to provide the state to the UI, and UI updates automatically when the state changes due to Riverpod's reactive nature.

Comment: New day - new run through documentation, videos, and tutorials.  I was successful with Provider package but Riverpod hasn't 'clicked' for me yet (obvious from the above code).

Answer (score 0):

The widget doesn't rebuild which makes sense since it is only watching `settingsRepositoryProvider` which will only react when the `sharedPreferencesProvider` changes.

```dart
final settingsRepositoryProvider = Provider<SettingsRepository>((ref) {
  // Watching sharedPreferencesProvider here will cause settingsRepositoryProvider to react when sharedPreferencesProvider changes
  final sharedPreferences = ref.watch(sharedPreferencesProvider);
  return SettingsRepository(sharedPreferences);
});
```

Calling `ref.read(settingsRepositoryProvider).setOnboardingComplete` will not trigger a rebuild on `sharedPreferencesProvider` and thus will not trigger a rebuild on `settingsRepositoryProvider`.

What you need is a `Notifier` to hold the state, the `Notifier` is initialised synchronously, the `toggle` method invoke the state setter which will notify listeners to react.

```dart
final isOnboardingCompleteProvider =
    NotifierProvider<IsOnboardingCompleteNotifier, bool>(IsOnboardingCompleteNotifier.new);

class IsOnboardingCompleteNotifier extends Notifier<bool> {
  @override
  bool build() {
    final settingsRepository = ref.watch(settingsRepositoryProvider);
    return settingsRepository.onboardingComplete();
  }

  void toggle() {
    state = !state; // Invoking the state setter will notify listeners to react
    ref.read(settingsRepositoryProvider).setOnboardingComplete(state);
  }
}

// Replace your Text widget and ElevatedButton
Text('Value: ${ref.watch(isOnboardingCompleteProvider)}'),
ElevatedButton(
  onPressed: ref.read(isOnboardingCompleteProvider.notifier).toggle,
  child: const Text('Toggle'),
),
```

Answer (score 0):

I sorted this out using StateNotifier.  The last tricky part was assigning state a new Object - otherwise ref.watch did not trigger a rebuild.  The dsp instance was the one I retrieved with ref.watch, modified, and passed into save.

```
save(DspPojo dsp) {
    // state = dsp;  // doesn't seem to trigger rebuild
    state =
        DspPojo.fromJson(dsp.toJson()); // create new object to trigger rebuild
    debug('sharedPref: ${json.encode(state)}');
    prefs.setString('dsp', json.encode(state));
  }
```